# Pass NULL value to rdlc report Boolean parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameter-passing, rdlc

I have radio button list. asp code:

```
  Auditing: <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLAudit" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" TextAlign="Left">
    <asp:ListItem Value="true" Text=" Audited"  Selected="True"/>
    <asp:ListItem Value="false" Text=" Not Audited "/>
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="ALL"/>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and I have RDLC Report with Boolean parameter as bellow:

[image: parameter properties]

I want to pass null value when select ALL option of radio button list.
I try this code behind

```
  If (RBLAudit.SelectedValue <> "") Then
        p9 = New ReportParameter("State", RBLAudit.SelectedValue)
    ElseIf (RBLAudit.SelectedValue = "") Then
        p9 = New ReportParameter("State", DBNull.Value.ToString())
    End If
    Dim RepParams() As ReportParameter = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9}
```

but this not work when `RBLAudit.SelectedValue = ""` . The error is `"The value provided for the report parameter 'State' is not valid for its type."`

How to pass null value for this Boolean parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it works after very much trying and failing...

```
If (RBLAudit.SelectedValue <> "") Then
    p9 = New ReportParameter("State", RBLAudit.SelectedValue)
ElseIf (RBLAudit.SelectedValue = "") Then
           p9 = New ReportParameter("State",  New String() {Nothing})
End If
```

any other idea?